# jenkins pipline : How to get the list of file from workspace?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, parameters, jenkins-pipeline

In a jenkinsfile i want to get the list of files in a directory in workspace and put them in parameters.
I tried with:

```
stage('select'){
    def workspace = pwd()
    files = []
    new File  ("$workspace/buildFile").eachFile(FileType.FILES) { files << it.name }

    BuildFile = input( id: 'userInput', message: 'Sélectionner un backup', parameters: [ [$class: 'ChoiceParameterDefinition', choices: files , description: 'Properties', name: 'param'] ])   
}
```

but i get message error "java.io.FileNotFoundException:"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the pipeline scripts are executed on the master, so when you do `new File(...)` you create a file pointer on the master and not the slave/node/agent workspace context. Instead you should use [`findFiles`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#findfiles-find-files-in-the-workspace) which is available in the [Pipeline Utility Steps plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-utility-steps).